# What is the best way to divide a numeric column into two different columns based on a binary column?

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL Server that keeps track of hours and if they are billable or not.

```
SELECT 
    Billable,
    HoursBooked
FROM
    Time
```

Result:

```
Billable HoursBooked
--------------------
   0         8.0
   1         4.0
   1         6.0
```

I want to divide the hours into new columns based on whether it is billable or not. The new columns should be `BillableHours` and `NonBillableHours`.

```
Billable HoursBooked BillableHours NonBillableHours
----------------------------------------------------
   0         8.0          0.0            8.0
   1         4.0          4.0            0.0
   1         6.0          6.0            0.0
```

I figured out how to get billable hours by multiplying the two columns together, but this doesn't work where billable = 0.

```
SELECT 
    Billable,
    HoursBooked
    Billable * HoursBooked AS BillableHours
FROM
    Time
```

Output:

```
Billable HoursBooked BillableHours
----------------------------------
   0         8.0          0.0
   1         4.0          4.0 
   1         6.0          6.0
```

What would be the best way to create the non-billable hours column?

Comment: non-billable = HoursBooked * (1 - billable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```sql
SELECT Billable,
       HoursBooked
       Billable*HoursBooked AS BillableHours
       HoursBooked*(1-Billable) AS NonBillableHours
From Time
```

I would suggest you to use `CASE` statement here too, if it makes more sense:

```sql
SELECT Billable,
       Hoursbooked,
       CASE
         WHEN Billable = 1 THEN Hoursbooked
         ELSE 0
       END AS BillableHours,
       CASE
         WHEN Billable = 0 THEN Hoursbooked
         ELSE 0
       END AS NonBillableHours,
FROM Time;
```

Comment: Thank you. CASE works a lot better than my approach.

Comment: `case` _expression_.